# Handling missing data for Exploratory Factor Analysis

Tags: missing-data, factor-analysis

I am trying to conduct an exploratory factor analysis in Rstudio. I'm using the psych package. I have a lot of missing data so I was wondering what is the most appropriate way to handle missing data? Shall I remove any cases with missing data or use pairwise deletion?

Thanks

Comment: you can either remove those events including missing data if it's not *time-series* data or **impute** other values like *average* value of that feature. there are always some nice library you can use to have better understanding about nature of data and missing values via some visualization.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It's not a time series. What would you advise me to do?

Comment: In the first phase, visualize them via easy-to-use missing data visualizations, e.g. in python using the library/toolset [missingno](https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno). in the 2nd phase, you need to think of the best replacement/imputation based on your project/task.